# SELECT INTO do not store null in to the variables

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I was trying to check the values from the two tables, and I only want to proceed to the next query only if the value is found in TableA. There is something wrong in the below logic, also when there is not data, it goes to exception instead of storing NULL into the variables.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SPOOL temp.txt;
DECLARE
    v_ATM TableA.CODE%TYPE := NULL;
    v_TBL TableB.CODE%TYPE := NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT TableA.CODE, TableB.CODE INTO v_ATM,v_TBL FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.CODE = TableB.CODE WHERE TableA.CODE = 'ABC';
    IF (v_ATM IS NULL) AND (v_TBL IS NULL) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No value found');
    ELSIF (v_ATM IS NOT NULL) AND (v_TBL IS NOT NULL) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found in both');
    ELSIF (v_ATM IS NULL) AND (v_TBL IS NOT NULL) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found in Table B');
    ELSIF (v_ATM IS NOT NULL) AND (v_TBL IS NULL) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found in Table A');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception');
END;
```

Alternately I was trying:

```
SELECT TableA.CODE INTO v_ATM FROM TableA WHERE TableA.CODE = 'ABC';
SELECT TableB.CODE INTO v_TBL FROM TableB WHERE TableB.CODE = 'ABC';
```

but still, v_ATM does not store NULL if ABC is not found, and goes to exception.

Comment: When asking a SQL question, it is almost always necessary to add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as the functionality and syntax varies widely between them. Please [edit] your post to add that tag.

Comment: Absent row have neither `null` nor not `null` value. It is absent. Handle `no_data_found` exception and proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--instead of selcting code col to get null/not null, select count(1) to get either 0/1 as output w/o errors

```
with 
TableA as (
--select 'ABC' as code from dual 
--union all
select 'DEF' as code from dual
),
TableB as (
--select 'ABC' as code from dual 
--union all
select 'DEF' as code from dual
),
q1 as (
SELECT 1 as id, count(1) as cnt FROM TableA WHERE TableA.CODE = 'ABC'
),
q2 as (
SELECT 1 as id, count(1) as cnt FROM TableB WHERE TableB.CODE = 'ABC'
)
select 
   cast(
   case 
      when q1.cnt = 0 and q2.cnt = 0 then 'Both missing'
      when q1.cnt = 1 and q2.cnt = 0 then 'TableA present, TableB missing'
      when q1.cnt = 0 and q2.cnt = 1 then 'TableA missing, TableB present'
      when q1.cnt = 1 and q2.cnt = 1 then 'Both present'
      else 'NA'
   end as varchar2(40)) as output_txt
from q1 inner join q2 on (q1.id = q2.id)
;
```

Play with the sql by hiding ABC and DEF and union all lines of code as desired to get different outputs for different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting from a row, not a scalar value so if there is no row there is no value.

If you `SELECT MAX(TableA.CODE) ... WHERE ...`

You will get a value to use